# Overlaying Google-Defined Localities into Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I am a Massive n00b with this so please forgive my terrible ignorance.

I'm trying to work out how to do what may sound simple in placing an overlay over some Australian suburbs on a Google Map on a website using its API.

I've been reading about overlays and how you can define polygons with coordinates as per http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#PolygonOptions - and its example.

I want to place an overlay on the suburbs of Black Rock, Beaumaris, Cheltenham, Mentone, Parkdale and Mordialloc in Victoria, Australia - so obviously I can work out the coordinates of that area and define it in the code. But this process would involve some work and time, probably not be specific and require many coordinates. What I was wondering is if anyone knows if/how it might be possible to use the MapTypeStyleFeatureType administrative.locality  object's of Google Maps API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType - which may already have this area defined with those suburb names - so I can get the overlay to cover the area of those suburbs as Google defines it? (for example, put those suburb names into the code and the overlay occur on them automatically?) (or something!)

Sorry for what this is probably a really amateur explanation and question but I thought I might be able to do this myself and it might be possible with the help of a few nice, smart people :)

Many Thanks,
Tom W

Comment: I'm trying to do something simalar but I want to do it for mutliple countries, did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Also looking to accomplish this, did any of you find something?